# How to start a yarn script with pm2 on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, yarnpkg, pm2

I'm in a project using yarn and want to start one of the scripts in the `package.json` with pm2 using this command:

```
pm2 start "yarn start"
```

It results in:

```
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [yarn](ids: [ 0 ])
[PM2][ERROR] Process 0 not found
```

I also tried:

```
pm2 start yarn -- start
```

Which gets me:

```
[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: C:\path\to\project\yarn start
```

The `package.json` is located at `C:\path\to\project\package.json` and has a script called "start".

Answer (score -1):

```bash
yarn run pm2 start server.js
```

You must be in your target directory

This is our solution to running `pm2` with snap

still working on startup script for `yarn pm2`